# Google Action integration with Smart Home Devices

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, google-home

I am trying to find solution to integrate my smart home device server to Google Action but I cannot find any google documentation or step by step tutorial on it. If anyone is able to implement google action with smart home device then please help me with steps I need to follow to achieve it. I have tried following this but it wasn't of much help https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/

Comment: Have you tried the [codelab](https://developers.google.com/actions/codelabs/) or [sample](https://developers.google.com/actions/samples/index)?

Comment: Thanks @Nick Felker for promot response, I will give these a try today and update my experience here